# Tooltip only shows up when I write something in the textbox

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

This is my code for a button in C# windows forms. I want the Tooltip to show whenever I hover, but it only works after I insert some text in the textbox

this is the code

```
 private void passwordTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolTip toolTip3 = new ToolTip();
        toolTip3.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
        toolTip3.InitialDelay = 1000;
        toolTip3.ReshowDelay = 500;
        toolTip3.ShowAlways = true;
        toolTip3.SetToolTip(this.passwordTextBox, "Not more than 50 characters, no special charachters!");

    }
```

Comment: If you create the tooltip in the TextChanged event it is only normal that you  could see it only after you start typing in the textbox. Just move this code after the InitializeComponent and you should see it even if you don't type anything

Answer (score 0):

you have set tooltip on wrong event. Best way is to set tooltip on Form Load Event.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.setToolTip();
}

private void setToolTip()
{
    ToolTip toolTip3 = new ToolTip();
    toolTip3.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
    toolTip3.InitialDelay = 1000;
    toolTip3.ReshowDelay = 500;
    toolTip3.ShowAlways = true;
    toolTip3.SetToolTip(this.passwordTextBox, "Not more than 50 characters, no special charachters!");

    //Tooltip for other controls
}
```

Let me know if you still face any issue.